# A linq statement with multiple group by columns not allowing a thenby

Tags: c#, linq

I am some what new to LINQ so please cut me some slack.

I have a LINQ statement that I have grouped multiple columns on.  Depending on the search it ranks every record with how much it matches the search.

- 1 pt. for First Letter of First Name
- 2 pts. for First 2 Letters of the First Name
- 4 pts for First Name Matching
- 8 pts. for Last Name    Matching

So the First Order By is That.  I then want a Thenby statement to order by FirstName

```
var ResultsListOrdered = from O in ResultsList
                                         group O by new
                                         {
                                             O.FirstName,
                                             O.LastName,
                                             O.SSN,
                                             O.Email,
                                             O.Phone
                                         } into g
                                         orderby g.Max().ResultMatch descending
                                         thenby g.Key.FirstName ascending
                                         select new SearchResultViewModel
                                         {
                                             ID = g.Max().ID,
                                             FirstName = ti.ToTitleCase(g.Key.FirstName.ToLower()),
                                             LastName = ti.ToTitleCase(g.Key.LastName.ToLower()),
                                             SSN = g.Key.SSN,
                                             Email = g.Key.Email.ToLower(),
                                             Phone = g.Key.Phone,
                                             ResultMatch = g.Max().ResultMatch
                                         };`
```

if LINQ statement works if you take out the thenby line.  But as soon as you put it in it does not work.

This should work.  Any help would be great

here is the error that it shows me when I hover over it

[image]

OK I AM ADDING THIS HERE FOR THE COMMENTS BELOW BECAUSE I CAN'T ADD IMAGE TO COMMENT

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify "does not work"? What happens when you try it, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message?

Comment: I added a pic above with the error when I hover over it

Comment: Is that book for a beta version of C# 3?! `thenby` does not exist in C#.

Comment: It says it is .net framework 3.5 (Beta 2)

Comment: Ok put that book into the bin :)

Comment: Check out [this](http://www.amazon.com/review/R9GPRH9KPGDVM/ref=cm_cr_pr_viewpnt#R9GPRH9KPGDVM) review of the book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`thenby` isn't a valid keyword, use `orderby g.Max().ResultMatch descending, g.Key.FirstName ascending`.

You can see an explanation in the [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx) operator:

> In query expression syntax, an orderby [first criterion], [second
>   criterion] (Visual C#) or Order By [first criterion], [second
>   criterion] (Visual Basic) clause translates to an invocation of
>   ThenBy.

Comment: OK, I just sent a pic from my LINQ book(look above) showing an example of it in query syntax.  So could you explain more

Comment: @MikeHewitt Maybe we should contact the author to explain it. According to Microsoft's documentation he's wrong. Query expressions are just sugar candy which get translated into method calls. According to their own documentation the comma translates to `ThenBy`.

Comment: yes I agree.  Thanks.  Everyone out there beware of this section in this book.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can use thenby in this fashion its not an Keyword but extension method.  In order to do what you are looking to do you would need to do this.

```
orderby g.Max().ResultMatch descending, g.Key.FirstName ascending
```

Comment: OK, I just sent a pic from my LINQ book(look above) showing an example of it in query syntax.  So could you explain more

Comment: Check out this Article.  You can see on there how the orderby is translated.    http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When using the query syntax, you separate your multiple sort keys by commas, not `thenby`.

Comment: OK, I just sent a pic from my LINQ book(look above) showing an example of it in query syntax.  So could you explain more

Comment: The book is wrong. Here's a list of C# key words: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb310804(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: thats all I need to know.  Thanks